# cloudwatch rule from sqs to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have defined a trigger to my `lambda` from SQS queue. I want the Lambda to get invoked after every 2 hours and pick 15k messages from the queue.

Is it possible?

If yes, then how. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very possible. You can write a Lambda function that uses the **AWS SQS API** to retrieve messages from a queue. Then you can use scheduled events to define when a Lambda function is invoked. You can use a CRON expression to set the schedule. If you are not familiar with using CRON Expressions to define when a Lambda function is invoked, see this example.

This is implemented in Java - but you can still set a schedule event regardless of what programming language is used to develop the Lambda function:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Actually my Lambda is getting triggered from SQS also, so right now the Request Handler is like <SQSEvent, Context>. I have a doubt if I add another trigger of Cloudwatch events how will the handler look like?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and, in my case, I changed the lambda to be triggered by a cron schedule (in your case, 2 hours). Then, in the lambda function you can query the [AWS SQS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-making-api-requests.html#structure-get-request) to get the messages in the queue. You may use [ReceiveMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) method to retrieve the messages of the queue.